# Delphi / MySql : timestamp in DB aware components

Tags: mysql, delphi, timestamp

Delphi does not use *nix timestamps. In other apps I have converted to *nix before storing in MySql and reversing that when retrieving.

Now I would like to try using DB aware components for the first time. How will it work for tiemstamps? Should I (can I) store in Delphi tiemstamp format? Or shoudl I convert to *nix before storing?

Comment: There is nothing magic, Epoch time is merely a number of seconds since 00:00:00 01/01/1970 UTC

Comment: unix epoch is - Delphi epoch isn't (is it a windows epoch?)   THis converts Delphi t/s to Unix    timestamp := Round((Now() - 25569.0 {Unix start date in Delphi terms} ) * 86400)

Comment: nope, Windows's time zero is 1601 :-) BTW, do not reinvent the wheel, DateUtils already have pair of functions handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For normal use your do not need to do anything.

I had used Delphi / MySQL for many year and all data access components I had used (dbexpress / zeros / MyDAC) do the conversion automatically.  In case I need to manually specify the timestamp value, I just provide the text format ("yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss")

Comment: +1 so, when your SQL says ... INSERT INTO ... "timestamp" ... you pass Now()   ?

Comment: If using MySQL Timestamp, you can set the timestamp field default to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, then you do not need to assigned any value to that field and just skip updating the field, the timestamp field will automatically update when the record is created / modified.  If you really want to manually give time (now) to the field, you can either pass CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or Now() or your desired time in text format "yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss".